# How to set default program via config file (and have it run automatically)?

Tags: gnome, default-programs

On GNOME under Ubuntu 14.04, I need to set the default program to be launched when a blank CD is inserted. However, this must be done by modifying the appropriate configuration file -- I cannot use a GUI to do this.
Additionally, I need that the application runs automatically, without letting the user choose (the same behaviour one would obtain by checking the checkbox in "Use this as the default application" in the application selection dialog).

I know I can modify the file `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` to specify an application, but I don't know how I can set the application to run automatically.